# Android change text color on click

Tags: java, android

I changed my `ActionDown` and `ActionUp` colors to match my original color and the `text/button` now goes `transparent`.

My style script:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MenuFont">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#CDCDCD</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_weight">1</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">left|center</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">35dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">175dp</item> 
    <item name="android:layout_height">fill_parent</item>
</style>
```

**Original working script:**

```
package com.pxr.tutorial.menu;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(0xFF6A5ACD); 
            break;          
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(0xFFFFFF00);
            break;
    } 

    return false;   
} 
}
```

**New Script:**

```
package com.synamegames.orbs;

import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {     
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch(motionEvent.getAction()){            
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
         ((TextView) view).setTextColor(0x4F4F4F); 
            break;          
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:             
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        ((TextView) view).setTextColor(0xCDCDCD);
            break;
    } 

    return false;   
} 
}
```

What i did was change the hex codes to match the original text color. Once i did that the text became transparent when clicked. What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use 0xFF4F4F4F instead of 0x4F4F4F.
And 0xFFCDCDCD instead of 0xCDCDCD.

00..FF is alpha value which stands for transparency.